# Image Projection with SIFT

Tags: image-processing, sift, projection

Recently, I am thinking about a problem regarding image projection. I have a larger picture as bellow.
[image]

I want to find the transformation matrix, x'=Hx. When the above image pass the transformation matrix H, I will get another smaller picture as bellow.

[image]

I have tried to use SIFT to find four major points and use these points to implement DLT algorithm. However, after executing SIFT, I find that there are many matching error as bellow. The distRatio is 0.5

[image]

I have thought for almost two weeks. Is there any different ideas which can be use to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you had a look to findHomography? You can apply then also a rotation using warpAffine().

Comment: Oh! Thanks for reminding me. I will spend some time looking to findHomography and warpAffine().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logo you are looking at is symmetric. For example, you could rotate it by 120 degrees and get the same pattern. If you take a look, many of the "errors" are not really errors. The same pattern appears in your image many times. It is called self-similarity.

You could do several things:

- Change descriptors to avoid confusion between features that are similar in an image.
- Instead of finding one match for keypoint, find 3 matches and test multiple combinations by fitting a transformation and checking which fits better.
- Limit the transformation by rotation angle, mirror, etc. For example, angle must not be larger than 60 degrees

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have already thought some parts of your comment before, but I have any concrete idea. And I have the rotated this picture 90 degrees. There are still some error. I think that SIFT is rotation invariant. Moreover, this picture is a special one. I have other different loge with is not symmetric and those results also have some error.